# Create download link based on img src Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have several different galleries of images that have image captions. I'm attempting to append a download link of the corresponding image to the end of each of the gallery captions. The download link needs to be based on the img src for each image.

I can get it to append the download link to the caption. However, it's also appending a download icon for each image contained in the gallery on every image caption. Instead of one download link per image.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <figure class="gallery-item">
        <!-- BoGalleryImg -->
        <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="http://creative.dev.j2noc.com/thehub/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/crkis-2515.jpg" data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1">
                <img width="300" height="250" src="http://creative.dev.j2noc.com/thehub/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/crkis-2515.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" aria-describedby="gallery-1-823">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- EoGalleryImg -->
        <!-- BoCaption -->
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-823">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://jira.j2noc.com/jira/browse/CRKIS-2515">
            CRKIS-2515
        </a>
    </figcaption>
    <!-- EoCaption -->
    </figure>

    <br />

    <figure class="gallery-item">
        <!-- BoGalleryImg -->
        <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="http://creative.dev.j2noc.com/thehub/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/crkis-2379b.jpg" data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1"><img width="300" height="250" src="http://creative.dev.j2noc.com/thehub/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/crkis-2379b.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" aria-describedby="gallery-1-817"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- EoGalleryImg -->
        <!-- BoCaption -->
        <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-817">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://jira.j2noc.com/jira/browse/CRKIS-2379B">
                CRKIS-2379B
            </a>
        </figcaption>
    <!-- EoCaption -->
    </figure>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.attachment-full').each(function(index, element){
        // create variable from img src
        var imgSrc = $(element).attr('src');
        console.log(imgSrc);  

        //Append Download Link to Caption
        $('.gallery-caption').append('<a href="'+imgSrc+'"  download><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt icon-download"></span></a>'); 
    }); 
});
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days now and I'm so close I'm just not sure how to get it to append only one download icon for the corresponding image. Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided.

My [CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/REDeyeJEDI85/pen/MrPWVK)

Comment: I cannot tell exactly what you want. Have you tried changing "$('.gallery-caption').append(..."   to   "$(this).append(..." in the last line of your Jquery?

Comment: Yup, Cybernetic is correct.

Comment: I tried what @Cybernetic suggested but it didn't have the effect I was hoping for. If you look at my CodePen link it illustrates what is happening currently. Notice that there are two download icons per image caption when there should only be one.

Comment: It works with a proper image url (yours doesn't work). 
Put this link in both your image sources (https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzHD_2FXauvA0P-Z6ot_sKSGYyD7hTRoOdPdKspyj6U1sghVgV2g) and you'll get the expected behavior.

Comment: See results here: http://gph.is/2B7otdc

Comment: @Cybernetic Sorry just realized the images that I am using are on a closed server. So you replaced the images src in the HTML and then changed "$('.gallery-caption').append(..." to "$(this).append(..."?


Can you share your CodePen link? Your gif appears correct I just want to analyze the code and replicate it on my side. I have updated my CodePen Above with the links. but I'm still not having the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is a bit hairy to parse. Here is some jQuery that reproduces your output with the desired icon count:

```
images = ['http://srsounds.com/j3/images/easyblog_articles/2943/han_solo.jpg', 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/chewie-db_2c0efea2.jpeg?region=0%2C154%2C1592%2C796'];
labels = ['CRKIS-2515', 'CRKIS-2379B']

images.forEach(function(value, index) {
    $('body').append("<img src=" + value + " width=350><br>" + labels[index] + " <i class='fa fa-download' aria-hidden='true'></i><br><br>");
    $('body').css('color', 'steelblue'); 
})
```

[image]

**If you want to use these icons bring in awesome fonts:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

There may be other requirements in terms of your gallery layout, but hopefully this will help you get started on a cleaner approach.

If you're having issues adding link attributes to your icons, or achieving additional layouts let me know.

******** EDIT ********

**If you want/need to stick with your original approach, then change your jQuery to this:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  download_ids_hold = [];
  imgSrc_hold = []; 
  $('.attachment-full').each(function(index, element){ 
      // create variable from img src
      var imgSrc = $(element).attr('src');
      imgSrc_hold.push(imgSrc)
      console.log(imgSrc); 

      //Append Download Link to Caption
      $('.gallery-caption').each(function(ind_2, elem_2) { 
      add_id = 'a_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
      download_ids_hold.push(add_id)
      if(index == 0) { 
        $(this).append('<a id=' + add_id + ' download><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>'); 
      }
      })
   });
   for(id=0;id<download_ids_hold.length;id++) { $('#' + download_ids_hold[id]).attr('href', imgSrc_hold[id]) }
});
```

We track the image sources and download ids, and use them appropriately at the end.

Comment: this makes sense. However, for my purposes this will not work. I'm using WordPress and I have several different galleries that are being populated dynamically. Therefore I will not be able to create an array of the available images as you have. I need the JQuery to first create an array of the available image sources from the page then apply them to the href of the html I am attempting to append to the caption.

Comment: I added an EDIT to make it work with your approach. You just have to iterate over each .gallery-caption and check for your original index (from the .attachment-full iteration) to be 0. I am using awesome fonts for the icons, so change to your bootstrap glyphs if needed.

Comment: Yea I had a similar thought and this works in terms of creating one download button per image. However the download link always uses the first img src in the gallery. Is there a way to force it to use the image that the download link corresponds to? i.e. Han downloads Han and Chewie downloads Chewie. I cleaned up my code a bit and implemented your solution [on this codepen](https://codepen.io/REDeyeJEDI85/pen/YYJbdG?editors=1011) Thanks for your help with all of this.

Comment: Changed EDIT script with a new one. Try that.

Comment: That worked! The solution was way more involved than I realized it would be. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: No worries. That's what we're here for. Best of luck on your application and continued learning.